# Change position of tooltip in AMCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

I have this AMCharts v5 which shows a tooltip on top of a data point / bullet

[image]

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/scaljeri/pen/dyZXXZX)

I tried to define a position

```
series.columns.template.setAll({
   tooltipX: 10
});
```

Although I'm not sure this will do what I want it doesn't work. When I add this code no graph is rendered anymore.

So my question is, what is the correct way of positioning this tooltip?
(It should also work when the tooltip is positioned on the right of course)